# How can we continuously monitor memory RAM + GPU usage while a notebook training code is being executed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, ram, diskspace

I'm new in Deep learning and Google Colab. I'm trying to run a training project on Google Colab. After 60 minutes of training code execution, google Colab starts displaying "busy" and the actual RAM + GPU usage + Disk Usage readings are not displayed in the Header bar on the top right corner. Please inform the code that we can continuously monitor memory RAM + GPU usage while a notebook training code is being executed.